# How to prove that an integral function is a linear transformation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, vector-fields

Let $f$ be a $C^r$ vector field in an open set $\Delta\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $F$ be defined by

$$F(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})(t,x)=I_d+\int_0^t Df(\varphi(s,x)) \dot{\varphi}(s,x)\ ds$$
where $\varphi:I\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \overline{B_b}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and $\dot{\varphi}\in X=\{\dot{\varphi}\in C(I\times \mathbb{R}^n:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n))\ | \ \dot{\varphi} \ \mbox{is limited}\}$ and $I_d$ is the identity of $\mathcal{L}$.

How to prove that $F\in X$? i.e. $F(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})(t,x)$ is a linear transformtion.

I don't understand how $\int Df(\varphi(s,x)) \dot{\varphi}(s,x)\ ds$ is a linear transformation. For $F$, applied at a point $(t, x)$, to be a linear application, the integral should be...

Comment: To clarify, do you claim that $F$ is linear in both $t$ and $x?$ Or are you simply concerned about the linearity of $F$ in the $t$-component?

Comment: @Carlo I need to show that $F(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})(\cdot,\cdot)\in X$, that is, applying this function at a point $(t,x)\in I\times \mathbb{R}^n$ results in a linear transformation.

Comment: To see that it is linear, just use the definition of linearity and the linearity of the integral ... where do you have difficulties?
Just prove that for any $(\lambda,\mu,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ $$F(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})(t,x)(λ y+ μ z) = λ F(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})(t,x)(y) + μ F(\varphi,\dot{\varphi})(t,x)(z)$$